# Are there traditions outside of South India of devotees merging with God and disappearing?

Tags: gods

case 1: Nandanar

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nandanar

> Nandanar entered the holy fire chanting the name of Shiva and reappeared in a new purified form. He looked like a Brahmin sage, wearing matted hair (characteristic of a Shaiva) and the sacred thread worn by Brahmins across his chest. His body was smeared with sacred ash. The gods showered flowers on the Nayanar from heaven and the Brahmins cheered. With the Brahmins, Nandanar went in the garbhagriha and saw Nataraja. The Nayanar disappeared in the image of Nataraja and became one with Shiva.

case 2: Andal

> It is also believed that Ranganatha of Srirangam Ranganathaswamy temple married Andal, who later merged with him."

Comment: The great Kashmiri Āchārya Abhinavgupta along with his disciples merged with consciousness in Kashmiri. Bhairava Stotra is said to be his one of the last creation before entering into the cave from where he along with his disciples never returned. https://youtu.be/O947L44aUYE

Comment: Unfortunately, the cave is struggling against Kashmiri Muslim fundamentalists. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Abhinacgupta+entered+into+cave&rlz=1C1RLNS_enIN768IN768&oq=Abhinacgupta+entered+into+cave&aqs=chrome..69i57.9396j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Many many devotees of Panduranga Vithal. Meera is also said to have disappeared into a Krishna's murti.

Comment: Nice one @Rohit. Too lazy to view the video, so, which kshetra did they merge into?

Comment: @moonstar Abhinavgupta cave in Kashmir. Google.